# 500 - Internal Server Error with lighttpd

Tags: php, apache, lighttpd, internal-server-error

I have a VPS with CentOS 5.8 (Final) and when I use lighttpd as my webserver instead of apache I get this error: "500 - Internal Server Error" (I'm trying to install WordPress and I get this error when I try to access my site; the error doesn't appear at all when I try to access other .html pages). If I switch back to apache then the error disappears and everything is fine. Why does this happen? I prefer use lighttpd because it uses less memory.

I also created a file names "phpinfo.php" and uploaded it to my server. When I access it, I get the same "500 - Internal Server Error", so from what I know, this would mean that my lighttpd isn't working properly, right? How can I solved this problem?

Comment: check the logfile of lighttpd (or use nginx :D)

Comment: This is what the lighttpd error.log file shows: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ANiGz76a

Comment: the php integration in lighttpd seems to be broken. cant help you more, this will be a step to step debug. i would suggest using nginx with php-fpm its as fast (if not faster) then lighttpd and php integration is simpler.

Comment: You need to make your logs more verbose - this is useless

Answer (score 0):

You did not properly configure lighttpd to run your PHP, or your PHP is failing.
You might not have installed php-cgi.

In any case, your question is poorly written.
See [How to get help](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/boards/2/topics/5)